# Determine web browser selection/focus color from JS?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, focus, selection

Is there any way, from Javascript, to determine either the system's selection color (the color it makes text that the user selected), or the system's focus color (the color that is added to the outside of a tab-focused link or form element)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, since browser setting/extensions can change this a lot. Perhaps there are settings for Moz vs IE that are specific to each. Perhaps if we knew WHY, there may be a better soln.

Comment: I'm working on an app-in-a-webpage whose UI, like GMail, will have its own "selection" of real objects, not browser text selection.  I'd like to match the system visuals, as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

These are basically yes and no questions, so it'll have to be no and no.